# IOS - cellForRowAtIndexPath is called more than once

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11

I have two devices, one iPad mini and one iPad Air. The iPad mini's iOS version is iOS 11.xx and my iPad Air's version is iOS 10.xx.

In my iPad Air, everything is working fine, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only called once. But with my iPad mini, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the first row of my table view is called based on how many rows my table view has.

I have been trying to solve this issue for a week now and I really want to know if this is a iOS version issue or code issue?

Here's my `numberOfSections`

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfSectionsInEasyTableView:)]) {
    return [delegate numberOfSectionsInEasyTableView:self];
}
return 1;
```

here's my `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSUInteger numOfItems = _numItems;

if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfCellsForEasyTableView:inSection:)]) {
    numOfItems = [delegate numberOfCellsForEasyTableView:self inSection:section];

    // Animate any changes in the number of items
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

return numOfItems;
```

Here's where I set the `_numItems`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame numberOfRows:(NSUInteger)numRows ofHeight:(CGFloat)height {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    _numItems           = numRows;
    _cellWidthOrHeight  = height;

    [self createTableWithOrientation:EasyTableViewOrientationVertical];
}
return self;
```

Comment: Please show your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: I've edited my edited my post @meaning-matters

Comment: Why that `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`? Try without these two lines.

Comment: Tried it, but still no luck.

Comment: You must be making a simple/basic mistake somewhere. Hard to figure out from a distance. All I can say now: Follow a basic table view tutorial and double check everything. Set breakpoints and check what's going on.

Comment: I was thinking that first but it only happens in IOS 11. I've run the same project on different device. One is working fine and the other one isn't. 
Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: I would print out the index path in `cellForRowAt` to ensure that it is indeed being called multiple times for the same section and row. If so, I would set a breakpoint and check the call stack; maybe this helps to find out why the method is called that frequently for the same section/row. Also, remove `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` case it is not needed here.